# How to properly set up environment for Lua

Tags: lua, mingw, msysgit

could you please help me set up environment for Lua in Windows. I have added following `C:\lua\bin` to the PATH system env. variables. But when I try to run file for example test.lua with `print("hello world")` interpreter probably sees the file but I get this message in git-bash:

```
$ test.lua
/c/lua/bin/test.lua: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token "hello world"
/c/lua/bin/test.lua: line 1: print("hello world")
```

And when I try to open test.lua in cmd there are no errors just the Notepad with code opens...but code in file isnt executed.
Thank you

Comment: if example is copied from internet (from browser), apostrophes can be wrong (sometimes)

Answer (score 2):

You can associate path extension with Lua executable like

```
ftype LuaScriptx86=c:\lua\x86\5.1\lua5.1.exe "%1" %*
assoc .lua=LuaScriptx86
```

(do not forget quotes around first argument)
And then add `.LUA` to `PATHEXT` env variable.
So you will be able run just `test` instead of `lua test.lua`

Comment: This solution works nicely in pure Windows, but not under MINGW (OP wants to run Lua scripts in git-bash command prompt).

Answer (score 0):

bash and cmd don't know that you want to execute the file using the Lua interpreter.

I assume that the Lua interpreter is at C:\lua\bin\lua.exe? If so, you should be able to run your script using the command `lua test.lua`. In bash, you might need to do `/c/lua/bin/lua test.lua` instead.

Comment: Yes, lua.exe and luadist.exe is in C:\lua\bin\ .When I type: 'lua test.lua' I get "lua: cannot open test.lua: No such file or directory" and when I try to use luadist test.lua I get this message: http://imgur.com/2RH7SOB .

Answer (score 0):

Example:

I have `lua53.exe` in the folder `C:\Lua\`
I did not add this path to system variable PATH.

This is my Lua file "a.lua" containing shebang:

```
$ cat a.lua
#!/c/Lua/lua53
print"Hello"
```

And this is how I run it:

```
$ ./a.lua
Hello
```

P.S.
You are allowed to terminate shebang line with Windows-style newline CR LF (such shebang will not work on *nix), so using Notepad to edit Lua files is Ok.

Comment: I have used exact same code, just changed the path but interpreter still doesnt see the file. I probably made some mistake compiling lua.

Comment: You can download Lua binaries `lua-5.3.4_Win64_bin.zip` from [here](http://luabinaries.sourceforge.net/download.html)